# How to sum an array formula over a dynamic range of data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in a Google Sheet. Column A represents the name of an invoice item, column B represents the price for the invoice item and columns C onward represent the people responsible for paying for that invoice item. The rows represent the invoice items themselves.

Example:

```
    A,B,C,D,E,F
  + --------------------
1 | Item,Cost,Person A,Person B,Person C,Person D
2 | Food,100,X,,X,X
3 | Gas,30,X,X,X,X
4 | Water,25,X,X,,
```

| Item | Cost | Person A | Person B | Person C | Person D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 100 | X |  | X | X |
| Gas | 30 | X | X | X | X |
| Water | 25 | X | X |  |  |

I am trying to write a Google Sheets formula to compute the total a single person is responsible paying for in the whole invoice. An "X" in the person's column means they are partially responsible for that invoice item. In the example above, Person A would be responsible for 1/3 of the food, 1/4 of the gas, and 1/2 of the water, so $53.33.

For a single row (e.g. food, row 2 above), I can compute a single person's (e.g. person A, column C above) share of the cost via:

```
=(countif(C2,"X")/countif(C2:F2,"X"))*B2
```

To get person A's entire share of the invoice, I would just need to sum all of the values computed with this formula. However, I'd like to do this in a single cell using `=arrayformula()` or a lambda at the bottom of each person's column. I have gotten close with (referencing example above):

```
=sum(arrayformula(if(C2:C4="X", B2:B4/countif(C2:F2, "X"), 0)))
```

But the range `C2:F2` in the `=countif()` needs to update dynamically based on which row the formula is being run on in the range.

Is there a way to do this in a single cell in Google Sheets? In the above example, I'd want to run this from cell `C5` for Person A, `D5` for Person B, etc.

Here is an example of the output table I am trying to build:

| Item | Cost | Person A | Person B | Person C | Person D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 100 | X |  | X | X |
| Gas | 30 | X | X | X | X |
| Water | 25 | X | X |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |
| **Totals** | 155 | 53.33 | 20 | 40.83 | 40.83 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=BYCOL(INDEX(--(C2:F4="X")*(MAP(B2:B4, BYROW(C2:F4,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(x,"<>"))),LAMBDA(a,b,a/b)))),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)))
```

[image]

If you want to add total of cost column then use `HASTACK()`. Try-

```
=HSTACK(SUM(B2:B4), BYCOL(INDEX(--(C2:F4="X")*(MAP(B2:B4, BYROW(C2:F4,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(x,"<>"))),LAMBDA(a,b,a/b)))),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! I had some sparse fields in the data that wasn't included in the example, so I changed the second lambda to `LAMBDA(a,b,if(b=0,0,a/b))`. Thanks!